# How to check for error when running mysql queries from an Ubuntu shell?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, shell-script

I'm running a shell script to do various things for me.  The idea is to add it to crontab.
Here's a sample command to `show databases`:

```
EMAILID="some@Gmail.com"

T="/tmp/cleanup.info"

echo "starting backup process at $Now " >> $T


MYSQL="$(which mysql)"
MYSQLDUMP="$(which mysqldump)"
GZIP="$(which gzip)"

mysqlport="3306"
mysqluser="someroot"
mysqlpass="pass"
mysqlhost="localhost"

echo "querying the database for record older than date $Lastweekdate " >> $T


DBS="$($MYSQL -u $mysqluser -h $mysqlhost -p$mysqlpass -Bse 'show databases');"

##if noerror then

## echo "success" >> $T
Subject="success"
##else
Subject="failure"
## echo "Backup failed" >> $T

##fi
## rm -f $T

/usr/bin/mail  -s $Subject "$EMAILID" <$T
```

So as you can see, I have no clue on how to check if the operation was successful or not.  Aside from that, everything works perfectly.

Can anyone give me a hand?   for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the error return code, It's $?